# Emulating laptop internal keyboard interface

Tags: microcontroller, keyboard, laptop

[topic background]

I have several older laptops (MFG 2000-2003) that have a missing keyboard. I`d like to test them if they are in working condition. All of them are in CMOS mismatch state (need to set RTC values to continue to boot). In this state I cannot use external USB keyboard. Buying keyboards are not worth if I dont know other parts are ok or not...

[topic]

I want to hit few specific keys like Enter, F10, F12, Esc via laptop internal interface (usually 30 - 36 pins) - like this:
[image]

I wasnt able to find a common principle of what is inside the laptop keyboard module. My guess its only the membrane matrix which shorts various combinations on 3O pin cable and keyboard is not powered? Is there some kind of generic pinout?
I thought that i could make a sort of MCU tester that could test all combinations for such problems....

Comment: There's no IC that those traces go to? And the laptops don't have ps/2 keyboard plugs? PS/2 keyboards most of the time can be used in Bios when USB keyboards can't.

Comment: Maybe they are just the contacts of the matrix, so.. you just have to find ou what are the right row and column pins... If you manage to find a working (or not working) keyboard you can guess it..

Comment: @Passerby This is not this case - no PS/2. As you wrote, they almost (but not) always have PS/2 - these are smaller form factors and have only USB. With PS/2 it could be super easy... :)

Comment: @frarugi87 I guessed this, good someone has similar idea.
After searching the web, found this website:
[link]http://www.rawiriblundell.com/?page_id=155
There is quite nice tutorial about different keyboard but guess its generic principe. Will try it on some keyboard :)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't mention the computer model or part number?

Comment: @Passerby I Thought its not neccesary. But for example I have two Toshiba Portege 3500. Some others are industrial unbranded laptops. But currently focusing most on Portege.